# c++: шаблонный член класса в обычном классе

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

У меня есть некоторый шаблонный класс `CExtractor<IExtractorData>`, экземпляр которого я хочу передавать в качестве параметра другому классу `CProgressManager`, при этом данный класс будет работать с методами шаблонного класса и напрямую и явно никак с `IExtractorData` контактировать не будет.

Делаю следующим образом:

```
class CProgressManager
{
private:
    template <class IExtractorData>
    CExtractor<IExtractorData>* m_extractor;

public:
    template <class IExtractorData>
    CProgressManager(CExtractor<IExtractorData>* extractor);
};

template <class IExtractorData>
CProgressManager::CProgressManager(
    CExtractor<IExtractorData>* extractor
)
{
    m_extractor = extractor;
}
```

и получаю ошибку на строчке

```
CExtractor<IExtractorData>* m_extractor;
```

> (active)  E0786   member "CProgressManager::m_extractor" is not a valid
> class member
> template
> Error C3376   'CProgressManager::m_extractor': only static data member
> templates are
> allowed

подскажите как выйти из данной ситуации, чтобы не делать `CProgressManager` шаблонным и в явном виде при создании экземпляра данного класса не указывать какие именно данные `IExtractorData` будут использовать?

Comment: *"У меня есть некоторый шаблонный класс CExtractor<IExtractorData>"* - а в коде объявляется шаблон переменной

Comment: @user7860670, так как проблему решить то? я не могу объявить это как `CExtractor* m_extractor`, компилятор также ругается, мне надо указать тип данных

Comment: Ну так вы укажите тип данных, зачем вы там вместо этого шаблон переменной делаете? и кстати CExtractor в приведенном коде вообще не объявлен

Comment: @user7860670, CExtractor не объявлен, потому что он никак не влияет - это некоторый шаблонный класс, указатель на экземпляр которого является членом другого класса. На счет указать тип данных - я его должен знать для этого, класс CProgressManager тип не знает поскольку с этими данными из CExtractor не работает (например, может получить через метод size() кол-во данных, но не сами данные). Т.е. ситуация - класс CProgressManager умеет работать с CExtractor вне зависимости от того, какими данными он внутри себя манипулирует. Как аналог - CProgressManager имеет указатель на vector, но тип не важен

Comment: *я его должен знать для этого* - вот именно. Нельзя просто так объявить указать на экземпляр шаблона не указывая при этом конкретный параметр шаблона, ведь шаблон с разными параметрами будет порождать разные, несвязанные классы. Делайте CProgressManager шаблоном, или делайте базовый абстрактный класс, от которого будет наследоваться шаблон.